# How to select bean to inject at runtime according to a flag

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, javabeans

My project is:
I try to invoke a remote server first, if no exception, do bean1.
If catch an exception, do bean2.
Looks like

```
try{
  //invoke remote server
  //do bean 1
}catch (Exception e) {do bean2}
```

The problem is I can not find a elegant way to solve this problem. First, I can not use Factory-bean to createInstance(), because its constructor-args ref many beans.

The second way I found so far is to use a select ref which reads value from property file( I want it at runtime)

So What I want to do is as followed:

```
flag == 0 when remote server is not connected
flag == 1 when it is connected
use this flag to control which bean is constructed at run time.
```

Comment: Have you considered the @Conditional annotation on the Bean definition (which it seems could depend on the flag state)?  You may be able to set up two Conditional classes which differentiate flag==0 from flag==1 and create the appropriate Bean accordingly

Comment: @IanMc I can not use Java Based Wire. Could we disable the bean and clear up all dependency of it at run time?

Comment: There is a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor that allows you to refine/remove any beans you want at startup.  Are you familiar, and will this work?